# How to store Ansible registered variables in a list into separate variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have a playbook which is supposed to create LVM volumes in an EC2 instance. The EC2 instance is of instance class m5ad.8xlarge so there are two instance store of 600GB that come with the EC2 instance.

I am getting the output of the lsblk to narrow the output to the instance store devices like below:-

```
    shell: "lsblk | grep -v nvme0 | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'"
    register: lvm_out
```

The above gives:-

```
{
    "lvm_out.stdout_lines": [
        "nvme1n1",
        "nvme2n1"
    ]
}
```

Now I need to run pvcreate on the two devices together like below:-

```
pvcreate /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1
```

I am wondering if "set_fact" can be used but not getting any idea on how to use it here.

Could you guys help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact question should be: "How do I prepend a string to every element of a list?"

To start with, you don't need to run a shell to get the information for your disks. This info is available in gathered facts in a variable called `ansible_devices`. You will see in the example below I can get the same list as yours with stock ansible filters.

Now to preprend a string to every element of a sting list, you can use the `map` filter calling the `regex_replace` filter. Putting it all together in the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
 
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            ansible_devices.keys()
            | select('match', 'nvme0')
            | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '/dev/\g<1>')
            | join(' ')
          }}
```

Which gives (note: I only have a single nvme disk on my pc, you will get your 2 disks separated by a space)

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/dev/nvme0n1"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

To go further, as with the above, you should not use `shell` to launch a `pvcreate` command but run this through the [`lvg` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/lvg_module.html) instead.

Comment: I could capture the disks idempotently. Thanks for that. However, when using lvg module, I am not able to create Physical volume spanning two disks, like so:-
  - name: pvcreate idempotent
    lvg:
      vg: vg_sys
      pvs: "{{ item }}"
      pesize: 16
    with_items:
      - "{{ lvm_1 }}"
      - "{{ lvm_2 }}"
The above gives this>> Volume group \"vg_sys\" has insufficient free space (29362 extents): 38400 required. and I know the module took into account the second variable "lvm_2". appreciate if you could help here.

Comment: Read the doc again. Join the full paths to devices with a coma. Don't loop.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        cmd: "pvcreate {{ lvm_out.stdout_lines|
                          map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|
                          join(' ') }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '(^.*$)'
        _replace: '/dev/\1'
```

creates the string

```yaml
        cmd: pvcreate /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1
```